# C# : Closing application with non main form

Tags: c#, forms, authentication

I have a problem with my application, I want to make a simple login page which send you trough a home page (login success), so I put this code on my program.cs that I could navigate trough forms :

```
static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Form1 a = new Form1();
            a.Show();
            Application.Run();
        }
    }
```

the probleme is that if I close my app (login page) before submitting, the app doesn't close...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself use this solution:

I use:

```
public static Form1 a = null;
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
   Application.EnableVisualStyles();
   Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
   a = new Form1();
   Application.Run(a);
}
```

and when the sign in button clicked, after the authentication process, I use:

```
this.Hide();
Form2 form = new Form2();
form.Show();
```

And when I want to sign out, I use:

```
this.Close();
Program.a.Show();
```

And when I want to close the application, I use:

```
Program.a.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precious reply!

Comment: You're welcome.I also added public static to correct the access to the class Program.

Comment: Why my answer got -1??

Comment: I don't know dude! It's not me ^^ I accepted you answer.. I can't vote anyway, I havn't enough reput.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your *Login page* is Form1, change it as

```
Application.Run(a);
```

Comment: I think if I replaced id I won't be able to close if from the second form.. that's why I changed the default code.. Now I can close it from the 2nd and not from the first. EDIT : no I was wrong, thanks a lot that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should start your application like this:

```
Application.Run(a);
```

Alternatively you can execute the following in the FormClosed event of your form:

```
Application.Exit();
```